# `clEnqueueFillBuffer()` fills a buffer correctly only at random

Tags: c++, macos, opencl

I'm trying to fill OpenCL `cl_int2` buffer with default values (`{-1, -2}`), however the OpenCL function `clEnqueueFillBuffer()` fills my buffer with *different* values each time I run it – the buffer is filled with the expected values only at random. The function returns error code `0`.

Examples of the snippet's output at multiple runs:

- `0 : -268435456`
- `0 : -2147483648`
- `0 : -536870912`
- `0 :  268435456`
- `0 :          0`
- `0 : -1342177280`
- `-1:         -2`

I'm running OS X 10.11.6 with Radeon HD 6750M and OpenCL version 1.2.

```
clbParticle_hashmap_lookup_table = clCreateBuffer(context,
                                                  CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                                                  sizeof(cl_int2)*this->CUBE_CELLS,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  &err_code);

// ...

cl_int2 default_hashmap_pattern = { .s = {-1, -2} };

clEnqueueFillBuffer(queue,
                    clbParticle_hashmap_lookup_table,
                    &default_hashmap_pattern,
                    sizeof(cl_int2),
                    0,
                    sizeof(cl_int2)*this->CUBE_CELLS,
                    0,
                    nullptr, nullptr);

clFinish(queue);

// copy and print the data:
size_t   hashmap_lookup_table_size  = sizeof(cl_int2)*this->CUBE_CELLS;
cl_int2* hashmap_lookup_table_bytes = (cl_int2*) malloc(hashmap_lookup_table_size);

clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,
                    clbParticle_hashmap_lookup_table,
                    CL_TRUE,
                    0,
                    hashmap_lookup_table_size,
                    hashmap_lookup_table_bytes,
                    0,
                    nullptr, nullptr);

clFinish(queue);

cout << endl << "Lookup table: " << endl;
for (int i=0; i<this->CUBE_CELLS; i++)
    cout << setw(10) << hashmap_lookup_table_bytes[i].s[0] << " : "
         << setw(10) << hashmap_lookup_table_bytes[i].s[1] << endl;
```

Comment: Can you try with another way of initializing `default_hashmap_pattern` ? I can see any evident error in the code. Also check the error code of the ReadBuffer

Comment: @DarkZeros `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` returns `0`. I've tried these initializations of `default_hashmap_pattern`, however none of them solved the problem;
1) `cl_int2 default_hashmap_pattern = { -1, -2 };`
2) `cl_int2 default_hashmap_pattern;
    default_hashmap_pattern.s[0] = -1;
    default_hashmap_pattern.s[1] = -2;`

Comment: why dont you use an array, instead of a struct? Yes, your target might be to use a struct, but at least you can check if the issue is related to enqueueFillBuffer or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your fill pattern is larger too large for your GPU. I ran into the same problem trying to fill a pattern with a `cl_double` which is 64 bits like your `cl_int2`. I think `clEnqueueFillBuffer` is invoking a built in kernel which doesn't allow patterns

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this. On a Macbook Sierra, with Radeon Pro 450, following script:

```
int N = 100000;

float *a = new float[N];

cl_mem a_gpu = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N * sizeof(float), 0, &err);
checkError(err);
for(int it = 0; it < 100; it++) {

    float value = 123.0f + it;
    err = clEnqueueFillBuffer(queue, a_gpu, &value, sizeof(value), 0, N * sizeof(float), 0, 0, 0);
    checkError(err);
    clFinish(queue);

    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, a_gpu, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                         sizeof(cl_float) * N, a, 0, NULL, NULL);
    checkError(err);
    clFinish(queue);

    cout << it << " a[N - 1]=" << a[N - 1] << endl;
}
delete[] a;
```

gives results like:

`Using Apple , OpenCL platform: Apple
Using OpenCL device: AMD Radeon Pro 450 Compute Engine
0 a[N - 1]=-1.39445e-31
1 a[N - 1]=0
2 a[N - 1]=0
3 a[N - 1]=0
4 a[N - 1]=0
5 a[N - 1]=0
6 a[N - 1]=129
7 a[N - 1]=0
8 a[N - 1]=131
9 a[N - 1]=132
10 a[N - 1]=133
11 a[N - 1]=134
12 a[N - 1]=135
13 a[N - 1]=0
14 a[N - 1]=0
15 a[N - 1]=0
16 a[N - 1]=0
17 a[N - 1]=0
18 a[N - 1]=0
19 a[N - 1]=0
20 a[N - 1]=0
21 a[N - 1]=0
22 a[N - 1]=0
23 a[N - 1]=0
24 a[N - 1]=0
25 a[N - 1]=0
26 a[N - 1]=0
27 a[N - 1]=0
28 a[N - 1]=0
29 a[N - 1]=0
30 a[N - 1]=0
31 a[N - 1]=154
32 a[N - 1]=0`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this bug ONLY on macOS, since Mar 2017 when I started to learn OpenCL (can't remember the macOS version at then). The GPU is GT 750M (which is probably irrelevant), and the `pattern` is a `cl_double2`. Same routine on a GTX 760, Linux, has no such problem. I suspect this is because the OpenCL 1.2 support on macOS is incomplete, as `clinfo` (compiled and executed on macOS) warns:

```
NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 1.0,
        but some installed platforms support OpenCL 1.2.
        Programs using 1.2 features may crash
        or behave unexpectedly
```

The "corresponding" CUDA API, `cudaMemset`, can only accept an `int`-sized pattern. However, the restriction is stated in the CUDA documentation, while the OpenCL documentation clearly used a `cl_float4` (same size to `cl_double2`) as an example. So this is clearly a bug, not an undocumented feature.

But I guess Apple has solved this problem in macOS 10.14, because THEY ARE DEPRECATING OPENCL!